# Test if there is a match when using regular expression in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using regex to grab a number from a string in my pipeline
it works ok as long that I have a match, but when there is no match I get  an error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index is out of range 0..-1 (index = 0)
```

There error happens when i try to capture the group on following line

```
 env.ChangeNr = chngnr[0][1]
```

How can i test if there isn't a match from my capture group ?

This is the pipeline

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'myApplicationNode'
        }
    }
    environment {
        GIT_MESSAGE = "${bat(script: "git log --no-walk --format=format:%%s ${GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout: true)}".readLines().drop(2).join(" ")
    }
    stages {
        stage('get_commit_msg'){              
            steps {
                script {
                     def gitmsg=env.GIT_MESSAGE
                     def chngnr = gitmsg =~/([0-9]{1,8})/
                     env.ChangeNr = chngnr[0][1] /* put test if nothing is extracted */                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groovy when you use the `=~` (find operator) it actually creates a `java.util.regex.Matcher` and therefore you can use any of [its standard methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) like `find()` or `size()`, so in your case you can jest use the size function to test if there are any matched patterns before you attempt to extract any groups:

```groovy
def chngnr = gitmsg =~/([0-9]{1,8})/
assert chngnr.size() > 0 
env.ChangeNr = chngnr[0][1]
```

Another nice option is to use the  `=~` operator in context of boolean, in this case, Groovy implicitly invokes the matcher.find() method, which means that the expression evaluates to `true` if any part of the string matches the pattern:

```groovy
def chngnr = gitmsg =~/([0-9]{1,8})/
if(chngnr){
    env.ChangeNr = chngnr[0][1]
}
else {
   ...
}
```

You can read more info on Groovy Regular Expressions [Here](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/)

Comment: Hi
I tried your method but I cannot use size method :-( 

`Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods size java.util.regex.Matcher. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature`

Comment: Then you can use 'groupCount()' instated, or use the Boolean conversion method.

Comment: it is necessary to accept the signature
I tried also the groupCount and get same requirement "to be approve by administrators"